# Jquery Get and Set specific range of selector

Tags: jquery, css

Fact:

```
<div class="item">
</div>

<div class="item">
</div>

<div class="item">
</div>

<div class="item">
</div>

$(".item").eq(1).css("background-color","red");
$(".item").eq(2).css("background-color","red");
```

I want to do something like, the item who has color "red" will be black when I mouseover it but other item will remain unchanged.

```
$(".item).mouseover(function(){
   var cur_css = $(this).css("background-color");
   ???? //Now what?
});
```

Please Help?

Comment: please clarify your question. What you need?

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is to separate css styles from javaScript code. You simply add or remove classname on one element, and the style remains in stylesheet.

The solution is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yangchenyun/2j6kE/)

You CSS

```
.red {
    background-color:red;
}

.black {
    background-color:black;
}
```

You JS:

```
$(".item").eq(1).addClass('red');
$(".item").eq(2).addClass('red');

$(".item").mouseover(function() {
    $(this)
        .parent()
            .find('.red')
            .removeClass('red')
            .addClass('black');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this)
        .parent()
            .find('.black')
            .removeClass('black')
            .addClass('red');
});
```

Comment: you program is very fine. but there is some problem in my case. I can not addClass due to the css color is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
$(".item").eq(1).css("background-color","red").data('color', 'red');
$(".item").eq(2).css("background-color","red").data('color', 'red');
```

then

```
$(".item).mouseover(function(){
   $(".item).each(function(){
       if ($(this).data('color') == 'red'){
           $(this).css("background-color", "black").data('color', 'black');
       }
   })
});
```

modify it according to your need.

Comment: Sorry dear, I want to change all the same item at once. but you code will change only one item at a time

Comment: I've edited my answer to change color for all matching elements.